# Custom Query from 2 tables and Spring Data JPA

Tags: spring, spring-data-jpa, spring-data, spring-data-rest

Exception:

```
org.springframework.core.convert.ConverterNotFoundException: No converter found capable of converting from type [org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.AbstractJpaQuery$TupleConverter$TupleBackedMap] to type [model.pojo.CarPrice]
```

Have 2 tables

```
+------------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field            | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+------------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| car_id           | int(11)      | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| car_brand        | varchar(255) | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| car_model        | varchar(255) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| car_plate_number | varchar(255) | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| car_type         | varchar(255) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
+------------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

and

```
+---------------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field               | Type        | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+---------------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| car_rent_details_id | int(11)     | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| cost_per_day        | double      | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| rent_start_date     | varchar(20) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| rent_end_date       | varchar(20) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| car_info_id         | int(11)     | NO   | UNI | NULL    |                |
| avaliable_to_rent   | tinyint(1)  | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
+---------------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

I trying to get whole data from Car and part of CarRentDetails

in my carRepository

```
@Repository
public interface CarRepository extends JpaRepository<Car, Integer> {

    String ALL_AVAILIABLE_CAR_LIST_PRICE = " SELECT c.car_id, c.car_brand, c.car_model, 
     c.car_plate_number, c.car_type, crd.cost_per_day, crd.avaliable_to_rent " +
            " FROM car_info c " +
            " JOIN car_rent_details crd" +
            " ON c.car_id = crd.car_rent_details_id" +
            " AND crd.avaliable_to_rent = true ";

    @Query(value = ALL_AVAILIABLE_CAR_LIST_PRICE, nativeQuery = true)
    List<CarPrice> findAllByAvaliablePrice();
```

Trying to map this to my POJO class:

```
public class CarPrice {

    private Integer carId;
    private String carBrand;
    private String carModel;
    private String carPlateNumber;
    private CarType carType;
    private double costPerDay;
    private boolean avaliableToRent;

+ getters, setters, to string
```

How can I map Objects from this Query ?

Answer (score 1):

Create projection interface instead of POJO

```
public interface CarPrice {
    Integer getCarId();
    String getCarBrand();
    String getCarModel();
    String getCarPlateNumber();
    CarType getCarType();
    double getCostPerDay();
    boolean isAvaliableToRent();
}
```

And format the query that returns the fields(map with alias) that can fits the getters of projection interface

```
String ALL_AVAILIABLE_CAR_LIST_PRICE = " SELECT c.car_id AS carId, c.car_brand AS carBrand, c.car_model AS carModel, 
     c.car_plate_number AS carPlateNumber, c.car_type AS carType, crd.cost_per_day AS costPerDay, crd.avaliable_to_rent AS avaliableToRent" +
            " FROM car_info c " +
            " JOIN car_rent_details crd" +
            " ON c.car_id = crd.car_rent_details_id" +
            " AND crd.avaliable_to_rent = true ";

@Query(value = ALL_AVAILIABLE_CAR_LIST_PRICE, nativeQuery = true)
List<CarPrice> findAllByAvaliablePrice();
```

**Hope this helps!**

Comment: Thanks, it's helped a lot.  
Do you know what defines order whitch variable comes first ?
My Json now looks like this :{
        "carPlateNumber": "ZS11110",
        "carId": 1,
        "carType": "CLASSIC",
        "avaliableToRent": true,
        "carBrand": "VOLVO",
        "carModel": "V40",
        "costPerDay": 89.0
    }

but better if this looks like this:
{
carId
carBrand
carModel
carPlateNumber
costPerDay
avaliableToRent
} 

the second json reflect order in my projections interface. How can I rearrange order to Json could look like the second one  ?

Comment: Simply specify annotation for json property order like
`@JsonPropertyOrder({ "carId", "carBrand", "carModel", "carPlateNumber", "costPerDay", "avaliableToRent" })`
on the interface `CarPrice`. Please mark the answer as accepted if it serves your purpose.